# Is CoreOS a good/recommended host OS for Docker for a non-clustered setup?

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm planning to try out Docker for a toy project, and since I'm on Mac OS X, I need to run it on a VM. I also plan to deploy this on a VPS, with hopefully the same OS. Is it a good idea to use CoreOS as the container host OS, or should I just stick with a more popular distribution like Ubuntu?

I don't really plan to do clustering anytime soon, so I'm wondering if CoreOS would add unnecessary complexity. It seems to me that you can ignore `etcd` or just use it locally if you want (with the benefit of possibly scaling later on), but I'm not absolutely certain on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can boot CoreOS with all of the default settings and have a fully working Docker host out of the box. All of the clustering features will not be running unless specifically enabled.

One benefit of using CoreOS as a docker host is that (if you use systemd functionality) the systemd journal lets you do things like tail output of your container without having to run a bunch of `docker logs` commands.

https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/debugging/reading-the-system-log/#tail-the-journal

Comment: Cool! Sounds good to me, then. I guess I'll use https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant to run it. Thanks!